How to execute the code after JavaScript will append the DOM child ("appendChild" method)?
I have checked the topics Javascript appendChild callback?. There, the target element is video, so the usage of loadedmetadata is the solution for that case.
In my case, there is the snackbar, but it is just a div.
I have expected that the below code will append the snackbar to body than will replace the CSS class Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState to Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState which will trigger the CSS transition.
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(snackbar);
snackbar.style.transitionDuration = `${ displayingDuration__seconds }s`;
snackbar.classList.remove("Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState");
snackbar.classList.add("Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState");

Contrary to expectations, the transition is instant:

But, if we'll add the delay after appendChild, the transition will be smooth:
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(snackbar);

setTimeout(
  () => {
    snackbar.style.transitionDuration = `${ displayingDuration__seconds }s`;
    snackbar.classList.remove("Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState");
    snackbar.classList.add("Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState");
  },
  500
);


It is NOT the solution, because we don't know how much the delay must be.
Large delay will be felt like application lagging while small delay (some milliseconds) could be not enough. This is the case when the callback for appendChild is demanded, but there is no such callback. What could be instead?

"small delay [may] be not enough" - try with 1ms (or 0).   You'll be surprised that it works no matter how small the delay

It comes down to the cycle: if you don't add the class in the same cycle, it will consider it "added" and not there initially. The best solution is probably to wait for the next animation frame, like new Promise( window.requestAnimationFrame ).then(() => { /*... add class here ...*/ }), that is the minimum delay for drawing anything anyway.

Similar to above, without promise:  requestAnimationFrame(() => { /* add class here */}); MDN

@fdomn-m Ah feck, you're right, I made it too complicated. It's that I tend to use await ... and then classList.add, but thats even more complicated in a comment.

What happens is a browser re-renders a page after a macrotask is finished (JS ends working after some event).
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(snackbar);
snackbar.style.transitionDuration = `${ displayingDuration__seconds }s`;
snackbar.classList.remove("Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState");
snackbar.classList.add("Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState");

What you do here is adding the element, change its classes, so when you finished the browser see a newly added element, that's it, no previous state of the element is known to the browser so no transition could be inferred.
When you add setTimeout to the equation you allow the browser to catch the CSS class changes before and after the timeout. You can set the delay to 0, no problem here.
For smooth performance (no setTimeout()) you can use requestAnimationFrame which is executed after all sync JS code and all microtasks are complete, so the browser knows the final state of DOM, which you can mutate right before re-rendering the page:


async function show(){
  const snackbar = document.createElement('div');
  snackbar.classList.add("Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState", 'Snackbar');
  snackbar.innerHTML = '&nbsp';
  
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(snackbar);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    console.log('animation frame');
    snackbar.classList.remove("Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState");
    snackbar.classList.add("Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState");
  });
  
  queueMicrotask(() => console.log('i am a microtask'));
  
}
.Snackbar{
  width: 128px;
  height: 32px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -64px;
  transition: top 500ms;
}
.Snackbar-Transition__HiddenState{
  top: -32px;
}

.Snackbar-Transition__DisplayingState{
  top: 64px;
}
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>



